# Objective C - NSArray and For loop structure

Tags: iphone, objective-c, for-loop, nsarray

Work got in the way of learning Objective C but i'm back at it now and this has been driving me crazy.

This is my code:

```
i=0;
    for (i=0;[photoList count]; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%i",i);
        NSLog(@"%@",[photoList objectAtIndex:i]);
        NSString *fileName = [photoList objectAtIndex:i];
        sendImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:nil]];
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(sendImage,self,@selector(savedPhotoImage:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:),NULL);}
```

photoList is just an NSArray like so, except with 24 objects:

```
NSArray* photoList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Photo 1.jpg",
    @"Photo 2.jpg",
    @"Photo 3.jpg",
    @"Photo 4.jpg",nil];
```

It works... It copies the photos to the camera roll... and then crashes with

2010-07-24 19:34:36.116 iCardz2go Poindexter[29662:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray objectAtIndex:]: index 24 beyond bounds [0 .. 23]'

I've tried various configurations such as

```
for (i=0;1<23; i++)
```

only to get 
2010-07-24 19:51:01.017 iCardz2go Poindexter[29908:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:]: method signature argument cannot be nil'

So it's reading the nil and passing it.

I know its going to be something real simple that I've forgotten. Why doesn't it jump out the loop at Photo 23 (the count)?

Your help is greatly appreciated!
P

Comment: How can the count be 23 if there are 24 objects?

Comment: You should tackle a tutorial in the C programming language as it will hopefully cover constructs such as loops. Objective-C is quite a thin layer on top of C so getting yourself acquainted with C will help you get to grips with Objective-C also.

Comment: Marcelos - Because I thought an NSArray counted from 0... doesn't it?

Comment: Valid indices will range from 0 to 23, but the count is still 24.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For loops in C and Objective-C look like this:

```
for (initialization; condition; increment) {
    // body
}
```

`initialization` is where you set up the loop; it's where you tell it what to start with. `condition` is tested for each iteration, including the first; if the `condition` evaluates to true, the body of the loop is executed. At the end of each iteration, `increment` is evaluated.

So:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    printf("%i\n", i);
}
```

Will print the numbers 0 through 9. What you probably want for yours is:

```
NSUInteger count = [photoList count];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    NSString *fileName = [photoList objectAtIndex: i];
    sendImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: fileName ofType: nil]];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(sendImage, self, @selector(savedPhotoImage:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), NULL);
}
```

Note the assignment of `count` outside the loop; it's simply an optimization so the loop doesn't have to send an extra message for each iteration (you could just as easily do `i < [photoList count]`.)

Does that help?

Comment: Thank you also. Still crashing with: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:]: method signature argument cannot be nil' It's driving me nuts becaise I don't know enough to interpret the error message.

Comment: Does your class actually respond to `-savedPhotoImage:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:`? You need to make sure that's implemented.

Comment: THANK YOU! That was the problem! I remember commenting it out testing... something... a couple of days ago and low and behold it was still commented out!!!!

But because I was playing with NSArray for the first time, and getting real advanced (LOL!) by putting it in a loop I automatically assumed the problem was there.

Your help and those above is enormously appreciated by me and other newbies. Usually I can find the answer just by searching but this had me stumped.

Thank you all! Hopefully one day I can do the same for people.

Answer (score 21):

Why don't you try fast enumeration?

```
for (NSString *photoFile in photoList) {
  NSLog(@"%@", photoFile);
  sendImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                               pathForResource:photoFile 
                                        ofType:nil]];

  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(sendImage, self, @selector(savedPhotoImage:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), NULL);}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I hadnt heard of fast enumeration until now... so much to learn.

But using your code it crashes before it writes to camera roll with the same error:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:]: method signature argument cannot be nil'

Comment: That is to say with the loop (and theres a mistake in the code printed above it is actually i < [photoList count]... it goes through the loop, writes the images, then crashes.

Answer (score 4):

Both for-loop conditions — `[photoList count]` and `1<23` — always evaluate to `true`. Try `i < [photoList count]`. Better still, use @Eimantas's answer.

Comment: Thank you so much... it was i < [photoList count] I don't know what happened in pasting. But that doesn't fix it.

Comment: Using i<=[photoList count] it runs and then crashes with:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray objectAtIndex:]: index 24 beyond bounds [0 .. 23]'
Does that help narrow the problem?

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
for (i=0;[photoList count]; i++)
```

The condition `[photoList count]` is always true.
I didn't read the whole discussion, though.

Answer (score 0):

Change your for statement to for(i=0; i<[photoList count]; i++)